# File not found error when serving Laravel with Nginx in Docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx

When serving my application using `php artisan serve` I can access Laravel via `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/teams`.

But when I serve Laravel via Nginx using Docker I get `File not found.` error when visiting `http://my_ip_address/api/teams`.

My `default.conf` for Nginx looks like this:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name my_ip_address;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

location /api/ {
    index index.php;
    root /var/www/public/;
    fastcgi_pass laravel:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location / {
    root /etc/nginx/html;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}

location = /favicon.ico {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}

location ~* \.(?:css|js|map|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg)$ {
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, immutable";
}}
```

Laravel container is avaiable. I can even successfully run `docker-compose exec laravel php artisan migrate --seed`

React build is also successfully served by Nginx - when I visit `http://my_ip_address` I see my main page for React.

I setup the project following my Github [repository](https://github.com/Ted-Rose/team_challenge/tree/6e1eadf5633f596d35fa1ff527928a78ae9e5a76) README file for HTTP.

Comment: Try using `location /` instead of `location /api/`

Comment: @aynber, sorry tried to be specific and shared only config for Laravel. Edited my post - now full `default.conf` is seen where you can see that `location /` is ment for React.

Comment: @aynber, Still getting the same `File not found.` with `default.conf` set like this (removed Reacts part):

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name my_ip_address;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

        location / {
            index index.php;
            root /var/www/public/;
            fastcgi_pass laravel:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
```